# Unresolved reference when using a generated AAR with Composables

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-jetpack-compose, aar

I'm in the process of porting my [FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial](https://github.com/leinardi/FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial/tree/master) library to Compose and I've reached the step where I should publish the new Compose library to maven central but, when I generate the AAR, all the composable classes throw an `Unresolved reference`.

[image]

The crazy thing is that the the enum on the same package is perfectly fine and so is the AAR of the classic view library. So, the issue seems to affect only functions annotated with `@Composable`.

The issue happens with both a debug and release AAR so should not depend on minimization on release.

And of course the issue does not happen if I import the gradle module directly instead of using the AAR.

Do I need to do something special to generate an AAR with Composable?

This is [build.gradle](https://github.com/leinardi/FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial/blob/master/library-compose/build.gradle) of the library module

Comment: How did you mimic the animation, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: I don't mind at all, my library is open source: I'm simply using `AnimatedVisibility` where I'm setting custom `animationSpec`s for the enter and exit animations so that I can add a delay for every action item: https://github.com/leinardi/FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial/blob/d7d87b6bee0b5723a8da0718ae13444b4730a15d/library-compose/src/main/kotlin/com/leinardi/android/speeddial/compose/SpeedDial.kt#L95

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is caused by the `packagingOptions`:

```
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            exclude '.readme'
            exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'fabric/*.properties'
            // Exclude the Firebase/Fabric/other random properties files
            exclude '/*.properties'
            // Exclude AndroidX version files
            exclude 'META-INF/*.version'
            // Exclude consumer proguard files
            exclude 'META-INF/proguard/*'
            exclude 'META-INF/*.properties'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude "META-INF/AL2.0"
            exclude "META-INF/LGPL2.1"
            exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.properties'
            exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.xml'
            exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'
            // for byte-buddy
            exclude "META-INF/licenses/ASM"
            pickFirst "win32-x86-64/attach_hotspot_windows.dll"
            pickFirst "win32-x86/attach_hotspot_windows.dll"
        }
    }
```

And, in particular by the `exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'`: this file is needed to access top-level members, so **don't exclude it.**

It would be better clear this exclusion list and only add what's necessary to get the project to build.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works when I removed "META-INF/*.kotlin_module"!

Comment: I had a similar issue with Kotlin delegates in a mavenLocal aar. Class imports were working fine but delegate imports were failing with unresolved reference. It was a tough issue to Google but luckily I stumbled across this answer, than you!

Answer (score 1):

The scope of these classes seems to be package private, compared to class `SpeedDialState`. Maybe take a look at other composable libraries, in order to see how they do it:
https://github.com/jetpack-compose/jetpack-compose-awesome#libraries

Comment: I don't know why you say that the scope seems package private: it's not. It's Kotlin, the default scope is `public`. And I already went to check many others open source Compose libraries but I found nothing special on their `build.gradle`. Anyway, on the Compose Slack channel they point out that I was excluding the `*.kotlin_module` from the build and that was causing the issue. I'll write a full answer now.

Comment: The screenshot tells a whole other story, while Kotlin is only the source code ...

Comment: From the screenshot you can't tell if the issue is the scope or something else and, if you check the answer, it wasn't a package private scope issue.

Comment: Of course I can tell, assuming that these imports are available. It's rather that you cannot tell what kind of Java bytecode the Kotlin compiler would actually produce... and apparently (based on your answer), you've broken the Java interop by yourself: https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/06/improving-java-interop-top-level-functions-and-properties/